# part of my code is unreachable in vscode, Iam trying to build basic rock paper scissors game

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, unreachable-code

I am working on rock paper scissors game in order to learn python but my code is being greyed out/unnreachable, how would you solve it?

```
import random

def play():
    user = input("What is your choice'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors\n")
    computer = random.choice(['r','p','s'])

    if user==computer:
        return 'tie'        

        def is_win(player, opponent):
            return 'You won'
    
    return 'You lost'
```

#FROM HERE IT IS UNREACHABLE

```
def is_win(player, opponent):
  
    if (player == 'r' and opponent == 's') or (player == 's' and opponent == 'p') \
        or (player == 'p' and opponent == 'r'):
        return True 

        print(play())
```

Comment: Please use code blocks around all your code snippets :)

Comment: You know python is a language, where the correct indention is very important. By the way you have formatted your question, it's rather hard to say, whether it is malformated just in the question or also in the code ... Please reformat your question so that your code looks **exactly** like in your IDE. If you don't know how to do that, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: And whats the `def is_win(...)` doing there in the middle of that function. While that is, in principle, perfectly legal, I don't suppose you meant to do that, but you would rather want to do something like `if is_win(player, opponent):` instead (and again, move it to the correct indention level!)

Answer (score -1):

I tried to regenerate your code

There were three wrong places at the same place

```
def is_win(player, opponent):
    return 'You won'
```

1. Here it should be `if` , not `def`
2. You have added extra indent to this block
3. The arguments should be `user,computer` , not `player,opponent`

And the last one. I don't know whether it's a typing mistake happened while posting the question here.

4. `print(play())` should be outside of the `is_win` function